# How can I get started presenting at conferences?

Tags: conferences

I would like to start presenting at UEx conferences about our experiences of combining UEx, web design and agile development.  It's all new to me - can anyone suggest a good way to start responding to paper calls, what sort of things to present, and how to put workshops together.  Any experiences appreciated!

Answer (score 9):

Although I haven't had experience speaking at any large conferences, **my advice would be to "start small."**

Hone your presentation with smaller audiences. I've started giving a few of my presentations to computer science and business students at a local college. Many times instructors are *looking* for a way to bring in outside experts on topics they don't fully cover in their curriculum.

I bring along someone from my own office to critique me and monitor the audience's interest. That person takes notes on the points in my presentation that are really engaging and when people start to nod off (super easy to tell with college students).

Once you've got some experience with your presentation and feel comfortable tweaking its message for different audiences, start submitting it to various conferences. Again, start small. Don't submit to IxD11 if you've only given the talk once in your life.

Answer (score 7):

What Kyle said :-)

Like everything else in the world practice helps with presentation skills. Try presenting at a local UX groups or a barcamps, etc.

You might want to look at things like http://lanyrd.com & http://speakerrate.com/ once you start speaking. One of the things that organisers are looking for is a track record of good presentations and feedback from the folk in the audience. Slideshare is another place to look.

As for how to submit - one thing I would say would be to *please* read the submission guidelines. I helped organise a conference track this year and I was somewhat surprised at the number of submissions that weren't relevant - or were unwilling to give sufficient information for us to assess their work.

As for your particular topic area - I think you'll find the User Experience Stage at Agile 2011 will be receptive to proposals in that area. Not sure when the CFP is coming - but it can't be too far away now so keep your eye out.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 5):

> how to put workshops together

Very good presentation on this

**How to start and run a successful local group or chapter**

http://www.slideshare.net/usableinterface/ux-organizations-how-to-start-and-run-a-successful-local-group-or-chapter